# Customizing Raster Labeling in LeafLet R

Tags: r, leaflet, transform, legend, raster

I have a raster layer with cell value ranging from 1 to 68, each number representing a different land cover type. how can i do it? I tried labelformat>>> transform. So far I can only work for the first number in the list.

[image: leaflet map screenshot]

and here is the code:

```
i<-1
findIndex<- function(v){
  for (num in classes[1]){
    for (t in v){
    
      if (t==num){
        return(classes[i,2])
      }else{i=i+1}
    
    }
  }
}
```

and here the leaflet:

```
leaflet() %>% addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.DarkMatter) %>%
      addRasterImage(r, colors = pal, opacity = 0.8) %>%
     addLegend(pal = pal, values=values(r),labFormat = labelFormat(
       transform = function(x){findIndex(x)}
     ),title = "Land Cover Classification")
```

error message:
'labelformat: the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used'.

Comment: What is the value of of the object 'r' that you are passing to addRasterImage() and values()?

Comment: R is the raster file, values is the cell values of raster file.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. My code end up looking like this.
"classes" is a csv file has code value(1 to 68) in one column and land cover type in one column.
"r" is the raster file.

```
     leaflet() %>% addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.DarkMatter) %>%
      addRasterImage(r, colors = pal, opacity = 0.8) %>%
     addLegend(pal = pal, values=values(r),labFormat = labelFormat(
       transform = function(x){classes[which(classes["Num"]== x),2]}
     ),title = "Land Cover Classification")
   })
```

[new screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jU633.png)